# Помогите отцентрировать блок относительно родительского

Tags: css3, вёрстка, позиционирование, html, css

Не получается отцентрировать .dropdown относительно li
http://jsfiddle.net/vLjthe8r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[так?](http://jsfiddle.net/vLjthe8r/1/)

```js
$('.menu > ul > li').each(function() {
    var li_width = $(this).outerWidth(true),
        dropdown_width = $(this).find('.dropdown').outerWidth(true),
        left = li_width < dropdown_width ? li_width / 2 - dropdown_width / 2 : dropdown_width / 2 - li_width / 2;
     
    $(this).find('.dropdown').css('left', left);
});
```

```css
.menu ul {
 list-style-type: none
}
.menu li {
 border: 2px solid #000;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 position: relative;
}
.menu a {
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
 display: none;
 left: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 padding: 0;
 padding-top: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 width: 200px;
}
.dropdown li {
 background-color: #000;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 color: #fff; 
 display: block;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding: 10px 15px;
}
.menu li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li>Some text</li>
                <li>Some text</li>
                <li>Some text</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Looooooooonger
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li>Some text</li>
                <li>Some text</li>
                <li>Some text</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```